# Determine the value of “c” using the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, tangent-line, secant

For the function $F(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$ determine the value of $c$ (critical point) at which the tangent line is parallel to the secant through the endpoints of the graph on the interval $[x1,x2]$. Not sure how to start this or do it at all so any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

Comment: Just apply the MVT. $\frac{F(x_1)-F(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}=F'(c)$ and compute $c$.

Comment: Both the title and the first comment seem to indicate that one is to use the mean value theorem. But you don't use the mean value theorem. This is instead a proof of the mean value theorem in the case of parabolas.

Comment: I’m supposed to use the MVT and I’m supposed to take the derivative in order to find the slope of the tangent line. I’m just not sure how to apply both of those in this situation to get the required answer since it’s with letters as place holders instead of actual numbers. I attempted to apply MVT but I got ((Ax2^2+Bx2)-(Ax1^2+Bx1))/(x2-x1) and it feels like I don’t get closer to the answer by doing so. If I could get more assistance than to “just use MVT” that’d be appreciated since I’m not entirely clear on how to apply it in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Mean Value Theorem:
\begin{equation}
F'(c) = \frac{Ax_{2}^2 + Bx_{2} + C - (Ax_{1}^2 + Bx_{1} + C)}{(x_{2} - x_{1})}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\implies F'(c) = \frac{A(x_{2}^2 - x_{1}^2) + B(x_{2} - x_{1})}{(x_{2} - x_{1})}
\end{equation}

We can factor out $(x_2 - x_1)$, resulting in
\begin{equation}
F'(c) = A(x_{2} + x_{1}) + B
\end{equation}

From this result, we can use the fact that $F'(x) = 2Ax + B$ and get:
\begin{equation}
2Ac + B = A(x_{2} + x_{1}) + B
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
2Ac = A(x_{2} + x_{1})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
c = \frac{(x_{2} + x_{1})}{2}
\end{equation}

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Perfect, thank you!!

Comment: I have a follow up question if you are still around or if anybody else sees this! It is the following and pertains to this question : For any quadratic function on any interval, at what point in that interval is the tangent line parallel to the secant line through the endpoints of the graph